# How to rotate around "camera" in opengl and c++

Tags: c++, opengl, rotation

My problem is that OpenGL always rotates around (0,0,0). But if I translate
the "camera", for example if I move backwards, it rotates around (0,0,0), too. But I need to rotate around the camera, so I would have to translate the points back to (0,0,0), rotate, and translate them to their old positions.
But here the error occurs : After the rotation, the translation is relative to the rotation.
So, how can I translate back ?
PS : I dont want to use gluLookAt()

So my code to rotate relative to the camera would be :

```
//set rotation to zero
glRotatef(-yr,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);  
glRotatef(-xr,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
//set points relative to camera
glTranslatef(-cam_pos[0],-cam_pos[1],-cam_pos[2]);
//reset rotation
glRotatef(yr,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);   
glRotatef(xr,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
//rotate
glRotatef(angley,0.0f,1.0f,0.0f);   
glRotatef(anglex,1.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
//and now, how to translate back,
//movement is relative to the cam ?
//I would simply use :  
//glTranslatef(cam_pos[0],cam_pos[1],cam_pos[2]);
//which wont work because its relative to the new rotation.
```

Comment: Can you share your codes to "translate" camera?

Comment: Yes, I can, but it doesnt matter.

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and try to be more explicit about your problem, the question is quite unclear for me

Comment: I'll ask this question again because almost no [on hold] question comes back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenGL does not support camera transforms directly. It assumes that camera is always located at the exact center (0, 0, 0). So you should transform all light sources, all objects and all other thing (all scene) using reversed camera transformation.

gluLookAt()  transforms elements using "reversed camera transformation matrix". If you don't want to use it, you should use model transformation methods of OpenGL.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3483744/4725899
https://www.gamedev.net/topic/421529-manual-alternative-to-glulookat-/

From [OpenGL's documentation;](https://www.opengl.org/archives/resources/faq/technical/viewing.htm)

> As far as OpenGL is concerned, there is no camera. More specifically,
>   the camera is always located at the eye space coordinate (0., 0., 0.).
>   To give the appearance of moving the camera, your OpenGL application
>   must move the scene with the inverse of the camera transformation.

Comment: Im sorry, but thats not really what I search for. Hope my new code makes it clearer.